# Can you set different JDBC Realms for different web apps in Tomcat 7?

Tags: tomcat7, jdbcrealm

I have successfully implemented a mysql server as a JDBCRealm for authentication in Tomcat 7. What I can't figure out is if it's possible to use different schemas or tables for different web apps. In essence, to define different JDBCRealms for different web apps. This way I can have different user credential schemas/tables to separate the web apps. I know this can be simulated with roles in Tomcat. I was hoping to find a way to make the web apps portable with their associated schemas. I have no idea how this could be achieved, so I have no code to post. Either code or even better, a topic to investigate further would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to configure your `Realm` inside the `Context` of your application. This way, if you have multiple applications deployed into the same instance of Tomcat, each of them would have its own realm. Also, encapsulating authentication/authorization details in the application context file makes your application more portable and easier to deploy.

Comment: Sounds like exactly what I'm looking for. I'll try this out and post working code. Thanks.